# how to add multiple imageview on listview row with horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to display multiple imageview and text view on every row of listview and number of row is not fix (number of rows integer can be fetched from server) 
How can i add horizontal scroll view in every row.
i am going to use for loop for number of imageview in getView method is it right way to do that.

My question is how can i inflate horizontal scroll with numbers image views in row in getview method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   // View vi = convertView;

    //if (vi == null)
    //{
    int Numberofimageview=2;

    for(int i=0;i<Numberofimageview;i++)
    {
        // assume i want to display 2 imageview in every row 

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row_layout, parent,
                false); 

        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Log.d("myapp", "position" + position);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
   // }
   // else 
   // {
       // viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();   
   // }
    viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(position));
    }

 return convertView;
```

}
[image]

This is xml for row

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wagon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wagon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/wagon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/video" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="title of file" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="type of file" />
```

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: @GauravArora yes i solved this...

Answer (score 0):

Try to include your relativeLayout into a HorizontalScrollView

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout>[...]</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: this will only add scrollview to every imageview ...i want to add scroll view to only row and i want to add item in it

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom listview. Create a xml file. within the main linear layout of the xml file put imageview and textview. Make sure the orientation of the linear layout is horizontal.. Make use of that xml file in getview methood